# Error installing PyGObject, 'glib-object.h' file not found

Tags: macos, python-2.7, gstreamer, glib, pygobject

I am trying to install pygobject for python 2.7 in pycharm for the purpose of using gstreamer. However I am having problems installing it. While in the virtual environment, if I use

```
pip install pygobject
```

Then the build fails and gives me this error

```
 gi/gimodule.c:25:10: fatal error: 'glib-object.h' file not found
 #include <glib-object.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1 error generated.
 error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

[full error log here](https://pastebin.com/KyewV8V6)

I know for a fact that glib exists on my system from searching for it with

```
find /usr -name glib-object.h
```

but for some reason the install can't find it. Do I have to link it in somehow/how do I go about doing this?

Also I know I can more successfully use this library with python3 but that caused some weird system errors that can apparently be resolved by using 2.7 so I am just exploring that at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

With virtual environments it's recommended installing `PyGObject` with `pipenv` instead of `pip`.

Install `pipenv` with either `MacPorts`, `HomeBrew` or `pipsi`:

**MacPorts**

```
port install pipenv
```

**HomeBrew**

```
brew install pipenv
```

**pipsi**

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi/master/get-pipsi.py | python3 - --src=git+https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi.git\#egg=pipsi
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
pipsi install pew
pipsi install pipenv
```

Once you've got `pipenv` installed then you should be able to add the package to your virtual environment:

```
pipenv install pygobject
```

↳ [PyGObject : Creating A Development Environment](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devguide/dev_environ.html#macosx-pipsi)

Comment: Unfortunately the exact same error occurred in pipenv